# Only in first input it works, javascript generated inputs with type color

Tags: jquery, html

I use a div

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

and a javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var s = '';
    s+='<input type="color" id="test1" value="#ffffff" />';
    s+='<input type="color" id="test2" value="#ffffff" />';
    $('#test').html(s);
    $('#test1').change(function() {
        alert('test1');
    });
    $('#test2').change(function() {
        alert('test2');
    });
});
```

Why doesn't work in test2, can anybody help me? https://jsfiddle.net/4eoq23a6/3/

Comment: what is not working in test2??? your fiddle gives two alerts...

Comment: you should use append... ya and both of them gives alerts...

Answer (score 0):

> ►Delegate attaches a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, now or in the future, based on a specific set of root elements

```
$( document ).delegate( "#test2", "change", function() {
  alert('test2');
});

$( document ).delegate( "#test1", "change", function() {
  alert('test1');
});
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4eoq23a6/4/)